Rx digital beamforming
I am using Rx digital beamforming with independent ADCs . These ADCs introduce quantization noise which I am trying to calculate and model. I am not sure though if that quantization noise adds in phase i.e. coherently or incoherently when the beamforming is done in DSP on the signal of interest after the ADCs. Any idea for someone who has experience with ADC quantization noise?
Thermal noise would usually add incoherently but what about quantization noise?

The conditions for quantisation noise to be coherent with the incoming signal, and so coherent across several receive channels, are somewhat restrictive. You need to have a very low amplitude of a noise-free single tone or a few harmonically-related tones.
Once any of these conditions are broken, you can pretty much regard the quantisation distortion as incoherent noise for signal processing purposes. The easiest way to ensure this is to have a few LSBs of real thermal noise in the system, which is almost always present anyway.
